# Bring the users identity from the presentation tier to the application tier

Tags: asp.net, wcf, identity, wif, n-tier-architecture

For our n-tier application we are looking for a way to use the identity from the presentation tier to the application tier. Our application is a classic 3 tier application with the following tiers:

- UI - Presentation tier
- Application / WCF tier
- Database tier

The application tier is not exposed to the internet and the presentation tier can connect by local network. Our problem is that a user logs into the presentation tier and we want the presentation layer to pass though the users identity to the application tier. How can this be done? Is it possible to do this with claim based authentication? We are currently looking to implement `IWSTrust13SyncContract` in a STS service, but it seems that the application tier must be reachable for the users browser. Can someone please give me some suggestions on how to approach this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Impersonation/Delegation or the Trusted Subsystem model - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905320.aspx

Impersonation/Delegation works best with Windows Authentication, but even then may require that your Presentation Tier server is trusted for delegation.  In this model, the Application Tier authenticates and authorizes the end user.

With the more common Trusted Subsystem model:

- The Presentation Tier authenticates the end user
- The Application Tier will generally want to authenticate the Presentation Tier, e.g. use Windows Authentication and only accept requests from the service account running the Presentation Tier, or some other authentication method, e.g. use a client certificate, only accept requests from specific IP addresses, ...
- The Application Tier trusts the Presentation Tier to authorize the end user

There are a number of ways to handle authorization:

- The Presentation Tier makes calls to the Application Tier via a Facade.  This Facade does all required authorization on behalf of the Applicaiton Tier.
- The Presentation Tier passes the end-user's identity to the Application Tier.  This can be in-band (pollutes your operation contracts with an additional parameter), or can be out-of-band, e.g. in a custom SOAP header.  If you use a SOAP header, you can make this transparent to your application code with WCF by using a behavior client-side to inject the header, and server-side to process the header.

  Whether in-band or out-of-band, you are trusting the Presentation Tier to authenticate the identity it passes to the Application tier.  Hence it's important to authenticate the Presentation Tier, and depending on your environment to protect against man-in-the-middle attacks, e.g. by using HTTPS.

Comment: This solution is on my short list although we prefer a solution with claim based authentication. Our presentation layer has a trust with our STS and our preference is to reuse the token to communicate with the application tier. We just can not figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

Your presentation tier will be using some form of claims based authentication (passive/active). Once issued with a token, you should use the ActAs or OnBehalf of on the channel to federate the identity down you n-level of services down the stack on your middle(application) tier. Let me know if you need a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class similar to User Identity and set the values in you Presentation tier.
and pass the reference of this calss to you Application tier.

Comment: If I would just pass the ClaimsIdentity class in my call to the application tier then anyone who has access to the application tier network can do that. There is no proof that the presentation tier had created the ClaimsIdentity that was passed along the application tier call.